# Unable to load chrome on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, apt, google-chrome

terminal did not load chrome. after trying to install with the app.
then do so on the terminal came back with this message:

```
raptor@raptor-Latitude-E6520:~$ sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unsupported file ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb given on command line.
```

twice attempted, R

Comment: Tried two methods - direct deb-download and installation from Software Boutique. Can't reproduce with Chrome 89.0.4389.90-1.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here originally.
I did get it in by some awkward procedure - then after 3 months it just suddenly refused to open.

So I just removed it and installed **Chromium** (the open source version of Chrome) browser instead. Working now - though I prefer Firefox for privacy.

Try on your admin CLI

```
$ sudo apt search chromium
```

to get the name of the package, then use

```
$ sudo apt install <chromium-package-name>
```